# Visualisation of JSON Data with Google Chart API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, google-visualization, visualization

I need to visualize dynamic string of json data with google chart API in ASP.NET. but I couldn't put these data in a data table to be used for visualisation. In fact these json data can be extracted via certain API of the database. I can't access the database directly.
the following is the sample of such a dynamic data:

```
{
   "APIVer":1,
   "result":1,
   "total_product":154,
   "returned_product":7,
   "products":[
      {
         "id":"430",
         "source":"SHELL",
         "action":"UPDATE",
         "type":"POSITION",
         "category":"ENVIRONMENT",
         "timestamp":"1367494024",
         "entities":[
            {
               "key":"station",
               "value":"6587"
            },
            {
               "key":"capacity",
               "value":"60612095"
            }
         ]
      }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can parse that in javascript to put the data into a DataTable.  What components of that data do you want to use to generate a chart, and what kind of chart will it be?

Comment: for example I need to filter these data by their category and timestamp and then show them in pie chart or bar chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic skeleton framework you can use to build your DataTable to draw the chart:

```
/* "obj" is your json object
 * this creates a DataTable containing:
 *     Category
 *     Timestamp
 *     Key
 *     Value
 * entries for each entity in each product
 */
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
data.addColumn('number', 'Timestamp');
data.addColumn('string', 'Key');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

var p, c, t, e;
for (var i = 0; i < obj.products.length; i++) {
    p = obj.products[i];
    c = p.category;
    t = parseInt(p.timestamp);
    for (var j = 0; j < p.entities.length; j++) {
        e = p.entities[j];
        data.addRow([c, t, e.key, parseInt(e.value)]);
    }
}
```

You'll have to tweak that to use the specific fields you want to chart.